# ConsoleKey.F6 makes the shortcut U?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a brand new programmer who is making his first application also known as a webbrowser. I'm trying to setup keyboard shortcuts to do different functions but I'm struggling intensely.

I'm very unsure as to what I'm doing wrong but with the below code it'll make the keyboard shortcut U?

I have no idea what the problem could be or how to solve it. I've looked around and I haven't seen anyone with a similar problem.
This happens with any project I try to open. If I have a completely blank Windows forms application and set Form1 Keypress with the following code, then the key U will open the mbox. F6 does nothing.

Other keyboard shortcuts do not work.

I have tried both ConsoleKey.F6 and Keys.F6.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.F6)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are just starting to learn programming and your first project is a web browser? Seems like a very steep learning curve...

Comment: Why use `e.KeyChar`? The F6 Key does not have a character, so the correct way to do it wold be `e.Key == Keys.F6`.

Comment: @IanH. this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @CSharpie I wasn't sure if its correct, I'll post it now, thanks :)

Comment: @IanH. Because for some reason the only available option to use is e.KeyChar. There is no option to use e.Key.

Comment: @EirikvanRiel you should use the KeyUpEvent

Comment: Then maybe further specify the environment you are working in? WinForms? WPF? There should be a `e.Key` in there somewhere ;)

Comment: try with KeyDown event, it is better for this purpouse

Comment: With KeyDown it actually worked. Thank you. Going to test it further in my Web Browser Application.

Comment: @DangerZone I like to start off hard. Of course it's harder but I'll learn more in a shorter time period that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First make sure the `KeyPreview` property of **the main form** is set to `true`:

[image]

- Then create the event `Form1_KeyDown` on **the main form**:

[image]

Use the `e.KeyCode` to compare the key pressed:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)   
{  
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the U key");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Works with KeyDown. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Only problem is now I have another issue haha. The keyboard shortcut does not work anywhere in the form. But I'll make a new question to that as it's a completely different issue. Thank you!!!

Comment: If only that was the case haha. I'm guessing I'm doing something else wrong for that but it only works when I'm either inside the RichTextBox that I use as the Addressbar, or within the actual WebBrowser function. Anywhere else in the form and it doesn't work.

Comment: The event `KeyDown` must be coupled to your *Main Form* of coarse. You probably made the event on the `RichTextBox`  itself. Select the main form in the designer and take a look at the events of it. Every control can have it's own events. So make sure you made the event on the *Main form*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `e.KeyChar`. The F6 Key does not have a character, so the correct way to do it would be ...

```
if (e.Key == Keys.F6)
// ...
```

EDIT:
Alright, I got the problem. The forms `KeyPress` function gets some `KeyPressEventArgs` which do not contain a `Key` property.
To fix this, discard the `KeyPress` function and use `PreviewKeyDown` instead. This takes `KeyEventArgs` which do contain a `Key` property.

Sources:
[KeyPressEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
[KeyEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Brand new Windows Forms Application.

Comment: And if I use KeyDown instead of KeyPress, then I have to use e.KeyCode, still no E.Key function. Not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the EDIT. Very much appreciated explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going about it slightly differently. the code below should work without issue.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey (ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == (Keys.F6)) {
        MessageBox.Show("This will now display!");
        return true;
    }
return false
}
```